# How to access body XML in PHP SOAP server

Tags: php, soap, ebay-api

When using the ebay API, it make notification requests to your server which can look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Header>
    Stuff in header
 </soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <GetItemResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
   <Timestamp>2015-02-22T16:19:51.956Z</Timestamp>
   <Ack>Success</Ack>
   <CorrelationID>3759873</CorrelationID>
   <Version>885</Version>
   <Build>E885_CORE_APIMSG_16971418_R1</Build>
   <NotificationEventName>ItemRevised</NotificationEventName>
   .
   .
  </GetItemResponse>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I define a function `GetItemResponse` then register it with the SOAP server object `$server->addFunction("GetItemResponse");`. The problem is that the function only gets passed the first element '' as the first argument. How do I get the full body passed to my function?

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the result to XML object like below:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
```

and pass $xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function GetItem($arg1, $arg2, $arg3){
    var_dump(func_get_args());
}
$soapServer->addFunction('GetItem')
```

GetItemResponse is node name that holds a response to GetItem call. Also you should add more parameters to GetItem function if you need them.

More information about parameters: http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/GetItem.html

If you really need full body then override handle method from SoapServer. It will allow you to get whole body.